# how to avoid encoding problems using ajax-json and php-postrgesql

Tags: php, ajax, json, postgresql, encoding

i have problems with encoding when using json and ajax.
chrome and ie encode umlauts as unicode when jsonifying, firefox and safari returning those utf-8 escaped umlauts like ¼Ã.

where is the best place to give all the same encoding?
js / php-get or by writing them to the database.

and i think the next trouble is, when i reload the utf-8 encoded stuff from the db, and write them to the browser and then rewrite them to the db, again via ajax-request a get a real chaos?

can i avoid the chaous? can i handle the encoding in an easy way?
pls. help :-)

very important is to also provide security

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing from your question and what went wrong. Perhaps some snippets would help.

Comment: i even didn't say something went wrong ;-). the thing is, that the browsers jsonify machines giving back strings with different characters for the same input, and the question is: how to handle that, best practice.

i think code wont make the problem easier, but one could stick to my code and resolve the problem for my special case - the thing is i am searching for a more reuseable solution.

Comment: You can set UTF-8 encoding in php.ini and if you are using Apache2 you can use the directive AddDefaultCharset with UTF-8 as

Answer (score 1):

You must set **everything** to UTF-8, this means :

Database collation

Table collation

Field collation

Your coding software (example notepad++) encryption.

Comment: [Collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) is not particularly relevant here, and you certainly don't set [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) in notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Maybe you are actually interpreting encoding the wrong way, clientwise. Try setting the frontend encoding before your queries.

```
<?php
$connection = pg_pconnect("dbname=data");
pg_set_client_encoding($connection, "encoding goes here"); //check enconding aletrnatives on PostgreSQL
$result = pg_query($connection, "SELECT whatever FROM wherever");
//and so on...
?>
```

I'm a newbie, but it may help. Also won't affect security in anyway if you are already protected against db injection.

Cheers